# Assessing code coverage for functional automated test scripts

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have been tasked with determining coverage of my suite of `Webdriver` scripts. Essentially, *what percentage of code do my automated scripts exercise?*

Are there any tools that can be deployed that would highlight code snippets that were accessed as the automated scripts ran?

I can also potentially use the results for assessing gaps in the automated suite.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JaCoCo](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/), specifically the section on [Session Import and Export](http://eclemma.org/userdoc/importexport.html). JaCoCo is an Eclipse plug-in. It's primary use case is to instrument code and show coverage within the IDE, which will highlight code snippets that were accessed. You can instrument your code, run your automated suite, and then import the execution data into Eclipse to view the executed code using the Session Import mentioned above.

Other tools that can accomplish this include [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) and [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/).